# RestKit 0.20 Named Post requests

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I am trying to post an object1 (managed object) and receive another object2 (not managed object).
I receive the following error:
`W restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:98 Adding mapping error: Expected an object mapping for class of type '<object1 class>', provider returned one for '<object2 class>'`

I know why this error happens, but don't know the solution.

Here's my code, how I was trying so far:
**Request mapping:**

```
RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"prop1", @"prop2", @"prop3"]];
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping objectClass:[<object1 class> class] rootKeyPath:nil];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```

**Response mapping:**

```
RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[<object2 class> class]];
[objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"prop4", @"prop5"]];
responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping pathPattern:@"myPattern" keyPath:@"" statusCodes:statusCodes];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

**Routing:**

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[<object1 class> class] pathPattern:@"myPattern" method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
```

**The call:**

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:object1 path:nil parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    // Success
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Fail
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `postObject:` if the received object isn't the same as the sent object. Instead, you'll need to generate the request operation (`RKObjectRequestOperation`) yourself and then you can specify the mapping for the outgoing data and handle the incoming data with a different mapping.

Look at using `RKObjectManager requestWithObject:` to generate the request and `RKObjectRequestOperation initWithRequest:` for handling the response.

Comment: Ok, but in this case will the RestKit do the parsing instead of me?

Comment: Yes, because you specify the response descriptors when creating the response operation.

Comment: But the base url and other url related stuff can't be used?

Comment: You're asking the object manager for the request to send, so it will use the base url.

Comment: Ok, I've got it. The last question is how to mark the operation as a post operation?

Comment: Should I use a named route?

Comment: to set POST, that's the method: parameter of the requestWithObject: method. (method:RKRequestMethodPOST)

Comment: Everything is ok with this way :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that @Wain answer is correct (I would like to thank him for solving a problem which made me losing 3 days). If you want to use a different object for the request and the response,you should perform your POST request using something like that:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_baseURL];
    RKObjectManager *restManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:url];   

    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [restManager requestWithObject:_objectToPost method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:_pathPattern parameters:_parameters];
                RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
                [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

                    // process the response
                } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                    // process the error
                }];
    [restManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```